Unix password sync with Samba 4 on Debian
I am trying to setup unix password sync with my Samba 4 on Debian 12 (bookworm). This should have been straightforward, but I just can't make it to work. Has anyone managed to set this up correctly?
Configuration
From what it seems, PAM-based password updates (pam password change = yes) are no longer supported. However, it seems that this is option is still set as the default in smb.conf shipped with Debian.
So, I ended up with the following configuration which uses passwd program/passwd chat:
[global]
    bind interfaces only = Yes
    interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0 eth1
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 2000
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *New*password:* %n\n *Retype*new*password:* %n\n *updated*successfully*
    passwd chat debug = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    workgroup = X80
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    use sendfile = Yes

Here is the local passwd dialog used to set the passwd chat, because the option in the default smb.conf does not seem to match the current behaviour of passwd.
root@nas:/root# passwd user1
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully

And here are the installed Samba packages:
 root@nas:/root# dpkg -l 'samba-*' | awk '/^ii/ { print $0 }'
ii  samba-ad-provision       2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 all          Samba files needed for AD domain provision
ii  samba-common             2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 all          common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  samba-common-bin         2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 armel        Samba common files used by both the server and the client
ii  samba-dsdb-modules:armel 2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 armel        Samba Directory Services Database
ii  samba-libs:armel         2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 armel        Samba core libraries
ii  samba-vfs-modules:armel  2:4.17.12+dfsg-0+deb12u1 armel        Samba Virtual FileSystem plugins

Running smbpasswd
And here is the smbpasswd output when trying to change my password as user. Output up to the last Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088235 comes quickly. Then there is a pause, before getting the final output lines indicating an error.
user1@nas:~$ smbpasswd
interpret_interface: using netmask value 8 from config file on interface lo
added interface lo ip=127.0.0.1 bcast=127.255.255.255 netmask=255.0.0.0
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.90.99 bcast=192.168.90.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface eth1 ip=192.168.91.99 bcast=192.168.91.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Old SMB password:
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 at port 445
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'ncalrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8235
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088235
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088235
tstream_smbXcli_np_destructor: cli_close failed on pipe samr. Error was NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
machine 127.0.0.1 rejected the password change: Error was : The transport connection is now disconnected..

My log files show a success in authentication. However, I don't seem to get anything in the logs as a result of passwd chat debug = Yes
